# Complex initialization in Custom QML type

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating a C++ class that will be registered as a QML type. I want to run some non-trivial logic when the object is initialized. I don't want to put this logic in the constructor because that is bad practice. In a standard C++ class I would usually create a Startup() function with this logic and call it just after initializing the object, but I have no control over this as objects are initialized in QML.

How should I implement this custom initialization logic for a custom QML type?

For those who want the details. I am making a QAbstractListModel that keeps track of all .txt files in a directory. When it is created it will scan the directory (passed in via property) and update its internal collection with the names of all .txt files in that directory.

Edit1: After looking at Qt's example projects I found that many of them actually do all initialization logic in the constructor, including things like setting up DB connections and doing an initial DB query and query parsing. One need only search for "database" from the Qt Creator Welcom->Examples screen to see these samples. I would appreciate it if someone found and explained a better way.

Comment: Why it is bad practice to create a valid object with all of its data within the constructor? When you have to call a setup method anyway you can do it also in the constructor.

Comment: If you google around you can find other reasons but for me it is mostly two-fold (and possibly out of date). First, debugging constructors is more difficult in C++. The GDB hasn't worked well for me when I try to add breakpoints in a constructor due to an exception that was thrown in it.

Comment: Second has to do with timing. If I follow the RAII principle, then I should initialize objects when they are declared. For applications with a UI this can prevent the UI from being responsive until all the complex initialization logic is done. I want to initialize objects as quickly as possible so the core of the UI can be displayed then fill in details asynchronously in a separate Startup function. For example, think about an OS. If the OS prevented the user from interacting with it until all startup services had been successfully started then people would get frustrated with the long boot.

Comment: I am not saying that the second problem is something that QT has a problem with; it is possible that it doesn't. These are just general practices. What I am really looking for is the equivalent of WPF's OnLoad event for QObjects.

Comment: I've never heard of it being malpractice having all the initialization logic done in the constructor. Where did you learn that? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Either way you can always register a factory type and have that one create your objects via a Q_INVOKABLE function call that returns the desired object.